# PhantomJS + Selenium Webdriver: Element doesn't become visible after clicking the button

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, phantomjs

I'm writing trsts for twitter using Selenium WebDriver + TestNG.
My tests run perfectly in Chrome, FireFox and IE, but there is a problem when I try to run them in PhantomJS:

On clicking "Tweet" button, the div element presenting New Tweet Popup becomes visible. This doesn't happen in PhantomJS

The code is like:

```
 headerBlock.clickTweetButton();
//Waiting for New Tweet Popup visible - this is where test fails
 waitForNewTweetPopupVisible();
 newTweetPopup.addNewTweet(text);

//Code for used methods
public NewTweetPopup waitForNewTweetPopupVisible() {
    waitForElementVisible(15, newTweetPopup);
    Reporter.log("<p>Wait for newTweetPopup visibility</p>");
    return newTweetPopup;
}

protected void waitForElementVisible(int timeout, WebElement element) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}

public void clickTweetButton() {
    click(tweetButton);
    Reporter.log("<p>Click tweetButton</p>");
}
protected void click(WebElement elem) {
    waitForElementVisible(15, elem);
    elem.click();
}
```

The screenshot taken in test failure confirms that popup was never shown.

I suppose that the problem is that javascript making popup div visible doesn't fire when clicking the button in PhantomJS.

Do anyone have any suggestions how to overcome this?

Comment: Can you post the code for your functions? Right now, it's not clear what they do and how they interact with the page.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto, Updated post with code of the used methods.